# Error in an expression

Tags: excel, function, expression

Excel returns an error when trying to validate this expression.

```
=MIN(ADDRESS(ROW()-12;11):ADDRESS(ROW();11))
```

Any help ?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you want to get the minimum value from a range?

Comment: Yes exactly. I think the double quotes returned from ADRESS is the main problem. How to get rid of them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Address function returns a string; not a reference.  If you want to convert that string to a cell reference, you need to properly format the string, and then use the INDIRECT function.  Note that the colon separator also needs to be a string, and not stand alone.

Something like:

```
=MIN(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-12,11)&":"&ADDRESS(ROW(),11)))
```

Change the comma separator to semicolon for your settings.

And make sure your formula is not in a row such that row()-12 is less than 1.